# Why is my UPDATE query slow in 22 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am working on my own advertisement system, every banner that gets shown inserts a record in the database (for statistics). one of the values is if the ad is being shown right now. then when you leave the page it updates the row and sets the value to 0. On an old table with like 4 million is around 0.1 seconds.

For some reason the query timer is above 1 sec

The database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_views` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `campagne_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `banner_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `position_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `device` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `on_page` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `ad_views`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `visitor_id` (`visitor_id`);
```

The SQL which takes so long:

```sql
UPDATE `ad_views` SET on_page = 0 WHERE visitor_id = 102577047
```

I have added an index on visitor_id

Version information

```
MySQL version 5.5.31
PHP version 7.2
phpMyAdmin 4.9.1
```

Probably the MySQL server version could be an issues because it is outdated (i can't upgrade atm) but should probably not improve the query time that much?

EDIT:
[image: EXPLAIN SELECT]

Comment: *"I have added an index on visitor_id"*  That is what you are saying but the `CREATE` does not show that.. Anyhow questions about performance should include `EXPLAIN <query>`, if you use a older MySQL version which does not support `EXPLAIN` on `update` run a `EXPLAIN SELECT on_page  = 0 FROM ad_views  WHERE visitor_id = 102577047` instead ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland the visitor_id can be found infinite amount of times depending on the behavior of the person. the more he looks around the more data

Comment: @Dharman it should have said 7.2 my bad.... but the problem is still there

Answer (score 1):

1. You need an index on `visitor_id`
2. You need to use correct types so the index is used

So:

```
create index idx_ad_views_visitor_id on ad_views(visitor_id);
```

You can have additional columns in the index, but `visitor_id` needs to be the first one.

Then:

```
UPDATE `ad_views`
    SET on_page = 0
    WHERE visitor_id = '102577047';
```

Comment: this is not an answer as he already mentioned index has been created on visitor_id and nothing has been provided new

Comment: @Andrew & RaymondNijland When a string is compared with an INT, MySQL will convert the string to INT. Thus the index cannot be used. So you need to use a string in the WHERE clause as Gordon wrote.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel but this has nothing to do with performance issue and also  ..Nanko has checked and it does not resolved

Comment: @Andrew Are you telling me, that the use of an index has nothing to do with performance? See [EXPLAIN example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c9QuVhR8QaocjHZQMTqgjV/0)

Comment: ... never mind @PaulSpiegel and Gordon i never noticed that the topicstarter is using the wrong datatype while selecting..    low on caffeine again it seams..